# Electron height in Browser Window is not propagated

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am setting the main window height like this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 702,
    title: "Home"
});
```

I can see that the width is all fine,
however the height is actually smaller for some reason:
[image]

i.e. 680px instead of the specified 702.

How do I enforce the 702px height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when a new [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) is created, the options `width` and `height` represent the dimensions of the window frame, which includes the window title (22 pixels high on my OS too). In order to set the dimensions to the contents of the window (body area), you need to add the `useContentSize` option:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1024,
    height: 702,
    title: "Home"
});
```

> `useContentSize` Boolean (optional) - The `width` and `height` would be used
>   as web page's size, which means the actual window's size will include
>   window frame's size and be slightly larger. Default is `false`.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Try `minHeight: 702` as the default is 0 and this might work

Comment: on the body? my current workaround/hack is to set it to 702+22, that gives me 702 height when I launch it.

Comment: I modified my answer, hope it helps as I can't test right now